# Problem with connection.readln waiting for carriage return

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm facing problem with TCpindy connection.readln method , I had no control in the other side sending data , when using Readln method in server side application hang (because receiving data don't contain carrige return ) , i'm trying readstring method but without success
Is there any suggestion to encouter this problem , me be looking for other component rather than indy ,

I need to get data from other client (tcp connection ) without any information about size of receiving data and without carriage return at the end of each frame.

Comment: What does the data actually look like that you are tring to read?

Comment: the data comes from GPRS Box, using wireshark , I saw data without any carriage return , and the length for frame is unknow for me ,

Comment: That is not what I asked.  I wanted you to show the actual GPRS data, as Wireshark shows it.  Then I, or someone else, can tell you exactly how best to read it with Indy.

Answer (score 1):

You have to know how the data is being sent in order to read it properly.  TCP is a byte stream, the sender needs to somehow indicate where one message ends and the next begins, either by:

1. prefixing each message with its
   length
2. putting unique delimiters in between
   each message
3. pausing in time between each message

Indy can handle all of these possibilities, but you need to identify which one is actually being used first.

Worse case scenerio, use the `CurrentReadBuffer()` method, which returns a String of whatever raw bytes are available at that moment.

Comment: Hi , thanks, the method CurrentReadBuffer() seems to be work for me